# Como Fazer Transition no Hover

Tags: jquery, css

Estou fazendo um efeito para MENU usando CSS e jQuery.

**Problema** 
O `transition` funciona do elemento para ele mesmo com ação `hover`. 
O contrário não funciona.

O CSS abaixo faz o seguinte:

Tem um MENU Mobile escondido a esquerda do site. E quando uso uma função jQuery para chamar a classe `.showMenu`, o MENU corre para a posição `left:0`. Mas quando clico de volta no botão que executa a função jQuery, o MENU não volta do mesmo jeito que veio - correndo.

O MENU simplesmente some.

```
// CSS
nav#menu-navigation{
    position:fixed;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 256px;
    height: 70%;
    top: 0;
    left: -400px;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    &.show-menu{
        left: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: left 0.3s ease;
    }
}

// jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.open-menu').on('click tap', function(){
        $('nav#menu-navigation, main').toggleClass('show-menu');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o transition está OK:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('div').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  left: -100px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
}
div.show {
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
}
button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Teste</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

---

Isso me leva a pensar que talvez o problema seja outro.

Olhando seu CSS, vejo que colocou `z-index: 1;` no `.show-menu`. Talvez você tenha colocado isso porque algum outro CSS estivesse mudando ele para 0 e precisou aumentar para 1 para ficar visível. Isso seria uma boa explicação para acontecer o que descreveu.

Então, tente adicionar `z-index: 1;` direto no `nav#menu-navigation`.

Comment: Parece que foi isso mesmo, hein. Eu já tinha corrigido. Coloquei um `transition: all .3s ease-in-out` no `hover` e funcionou. Mas para melhorar no desempenho mesmo que mínimo usei sua solução.